# if statement when comparing rows in 2 data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, match

I have 2 data frames data2 and data3:

```
data0 = {
    'state':  ['CA', 'CA', 'OH'],
    'year':   [2012, 2014, 2010],
    's': [2000, 4000, 5000]
     }
data1=pd.DataFrame(data0)

data2 = {
    'state':  ['CA', 'CA', 'OH'],
    'year':   [2012, 2014, 2010],
    's': [2000, 4000, None]
     }
data3=pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

First I want to count s by state and year:

```
data11 = data1.groupby(['state', 'year'])['s'].agg({'result1': 'count'})
data33 = data3.groupby(['state', 'year'])['s'].agg({'result2': 'count'})
```

The question is how to write a statement that

i) if every row count (result1 column) in data11 is equal to every row count (result2) in data33 print "all rows matched" (here do not show the matching rows)

ii) else print "the following rows failed" (and shows the rows that failed from both data11 and data33)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for one DataFrame:

```
df = pd.concat([data11, data33], axis=1)
print (df)
            result1  result2
state year                  
CA    2012        1        1
      2014        1        1
OH    2010        1        0
```

Then compare both columns with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and test if all rows match by [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html), if not filter non matched rows by inverted mask by `~`:

```
m = df['result1'].eq(df['result2'])
if m.all():
    print ("all rows matched")
else:
    print ("the following rows failed")
    print (df[~m])
```

---

```
the following rows failed
            result1  result2
state year                  
OH    2010        1        0
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I wanted-- thanks much jezrael!!